# Asp.net MVC SQL Server connection return null

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server on localhost. My code is as follows.

```
public SqlConnection con;

// To Handle connection related activities
private void connection()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source = MACHINE-VOIV7EH\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = geolog; Persist Security Info = False; "].ToString();
    con = new SqlConnection(constr);
}

public List<Bob> GetAllBobs()
{
    try
    {
        connection();
        con.Open();

        IList<Bob> EmpList = SqlMapper.Query<Bob>(con, "GetBobs").ToList();
        con.Close();

        return EmpList.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**con** return null

SQL Server settings:

[image]

Configuration from Pyton (try, but another database):

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                        r'SERVER=MACHINE-VOIV7EH\SQLEXPRESS;'
                        r'DATABASE=vibori;'
                        r' autocommit=True'
                        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem is with your connection string**. You should reference your connection string from the `web.config` file.

**Web.Config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="master" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=ACHINE-VOIV7EH\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=geolog;Integrated Security=False;User Id=your_user_id;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**C# File**

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["master"].ConnectionString);
```

Or **you can just send a connection string** as follows

```
private void connection()
{
   string constr = "Data Source=MACHINE-VOIV7EH\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = geolog; Persist Security Info = False;";
   con = new SqlConnection(constr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The string index of `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[string]` is the connection name, not the connection string which is what it returns. Use your web configuration file (`web.config`) to add one or more named connection strings which can be returned by this indexer.

Example:

```
string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString
```

and partial `web.config` content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MACHINE-VOIV7EH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vibori" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```